# Probabilities for selections from a set

Tags: probability

This seems like it would be a common question, but I can't come up with a search that provides an answer to my question, so I'm asking it here.

I have a set of unique numbers `y` numbers long. What's the probability of having at least on duplicate when randomly selecting `x` sets of `z` numbers from `y`?

As a side question, is there a better way to ask this?

Update:

1. I am doing replacement.
2. If I draw {1,2} the first time and {2,3} the second time, 2 is a duplicate.

Comment: You need to add more context. Are you randomly selecting them and then replacing or not? For example, if $Y=\{1,2,3\}$ and $z=2$, can I draw $\{1,2\}$ twice? Second, what counts as a duplicate? If I draw $\{1,2\}$ the first time and $\{2,3\}$ the second time, did I make a duplicate or not?

Answer (score 1):

The complement to the event you want is of selecting no duplicates among these sets.   This is, of course, only possible if $xz\leq y$, so if that's given then:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(\text{at least one duplicate}) & =1 - \mathsf P(\text{no duplicates})
\\[2ex] & = 1 - \prod_{k=1}^{x-1}\left(\dfrac{\dbinom{y-kz}{z}}{\dbinom{y}{z}}\right)
\\[2ex] & = 1 - \dfrac{\dbinom{y-z}{\underbrace{z,z,...,z}_{(x-1)\text{ times}},y-xz}}{\dbinom{y}{z}^{x-1}}
\end{align}$$

---

**To add context:** I'm assuming the process is to select $z$ numbers without replacement, then replace and so select another $z$ numbers, repeating $x$ times.  Further I'm assuming "duplicate" means, "the sets contain a common element", rather than "contain the same elements".